# Add additional total row after grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm creating an SSRS report where I need to display the sum of values by a group, and I need to create master groupings for these groups. I'm wondering if this is possible. If not, is it possible to just add another row to sum a grouped query?

My current code is as follows:

```
    SELECT ISNULL([MasterGroup],'Other') AS 'Receipts',
    SUM([ReceiptAmount]) AS 'Sum'
    FROM TableA
    WHERE [MasterGroup] IN ('Other','A','B','C','D','E')
    GROUP BY [MasterGroup]
```

Unfortunately, only A-E groups are showing, the NULL which was replaced as other is not showing too.

What I'm currently seeing:

[image: current query result]

If possible, this is what I would like to output:

[image: what I would like to see]

If I'm not able to do this in a single query, I can probably create multiple rows to reach my end goal and what I would like to output is this:

[image: If this is not possible, this is what I would like to output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grouping sets`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CustomGroup, 'Total') as CustomerGroup,
       Mastergroup AS Receipts, SUM(ReceiptAmount) AS 'Sum'
FROM TableA a CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN MasterGroup in ('A', 'B') THEN 'Group 1'
                   WHEN MasterGroup in ('C', 'D') THEN 'Group 2'
                   WHEN MasterGroup in ('E') THEN 'Group 3'
              END)
     ) v(custom_group)
WHERE [MasterGroup] IN ('Other','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (CustomGroup, Mastergroup), (CustomGroup) );
```

The format is a little different from what you specified but it should be similar enough.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, but just a couple of points. Unfortunately 'other' (the null value) is actually still not displaying. Also "NULL" is appearing as the total row, is there a way I can replace the NULL which totals the group into a "Total" string.

Current output 

!(https://i.imgur.com/lGb1rcC.png)

What I would like to see 
!(https://i.imgur.com/ukbWaFG.png)

Comment: @varnhem . . . The simplest method (which works in this case) is to use `COALESCE()`.